# Integration in question could not be resolved.

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

I do not know how to solve this integration

Comment: The integrand is just the $\sec^2$ in disguise.

Answer (score 3):

$e^x$ and $\log x$ are inverse functions, in the sense that $e^{\log x} = \log(e^x) = x$. And so you really just have $\displaystyle \int \sec^2 x \mathrm d x$.

As an aside, since you know the derivative of $\tan x$, and antiderivatives are unique up to constants, you know that the integrand must be $\sec^2 x$ up to a constant.

Answer (score 1):

First note that
$$ \frac{1}{\cos x}=\sec x $$
So then
$$ \int e^{-\ln(\cos x)}\sec x\ dx= \int \frac{1}{e^{\ln(\cos x)}}\sec x\ dx $$
$$ = \int \frac{\sec x}{\cos x}\ dx= \int \sec^2 x\ dx=\int 1+\tan^2 x\ dx $$
$$=\int dx+\int \frac{\sin^2 x}{\cos^2 x}dx= x+\int \frac{\sin^2 x}{\cos^2 x}dx +C $$
Now let's use integration by parts
$$u=\sin x\Rightarrow du=\cos x\ dx$$
$$dv=\frac{\sin x}{\cos^2 x}dx\Rightarrow v=\sec x=\frac{1}{\cos x}$$
So now we have
$$ x+\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}-\int \frac{\cos x}{\cos x}dx+C= x+\tan x-x +C=\tan x+C$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that $e^{-\ln(\cos(x))}=\sec(x)$.